# Is it viable to use Set in C++ to sort an array of distinct elements?

Tags: c++, sorting, set

As insertion in Set takes O(logN) time, isn't it better than conventional sorting algorithms (quick sort, merge sort etc) which at average performs at O(NlogN) time complexity?

Comment: By the time you've inserted n elements you're back to n log n complexity

Comment: std::set, which is typically implemented with a binary tree will have `O(lg N)` insertion time. To insert N elements into a set is O(N lg N).

Comment: quicksort can sort in place. std::set would make a copy.

Comment: The additional dynamic allocations for the set elements would likely add a significant burden to the time taken.

Comment: From what I remember, `set` internally uses `map` with values set to some dummy value. `map` uses red black trees internally to implement balanced binary search tree.

Comment: @kiner_shah the implementations I know of use the same base template for `set` and `map`, not one using the other.

Comment: @kiner_shah That's one possible implementation, but nothing that's required by the standard.

Comment: @Caleth, yeah you may be right.

Comment: @molbdnilo, indeed, other implementations are possible. Although, even [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) states that usual implementation is using rb-trees.